# Undefined on the first click in the second one it works | React/Redux/axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Im building a web app with react, I have a Header with a dropdown and it contains Link to a component that makes an axios get request and I save the response in the state, then i access to the data like **{this.state.authData.authorizationDocumentConfiguration.optionFieldMap.documentTypeOption.label}**
The first time that its clicked it throws me this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'optionFieldMap' of undefined` but if Double click it, it actually works and renders the corresponding data.

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchUser } from '../../actions';

import PatientCard from './patient_card';

class PatientAdmission extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { authData: [] };

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.fetchUser(id);

    axios.get("http://ec2-54-221-173-39.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8181/cxf/Demo/demo/get/inpatient-authorization-configuration")
      .then(response => this.setState({ authData: response.data }));
  }
  render(){
    const { user } = this.props;

    console.log('user  this.props response: ',user);

    if(!user){
      return <div>loading...</div>;
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <PatientCard
          dob={user.member.dateOfBirth}
        />        {this.state.authData.authorizationDocumentConfiguration.optionFieldMap.documentTypeOption.label}                        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps({ users }, ownProps) {
  return { user: users[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return {
    fetchUser: id => fetchUser(id, dispatch)
 }
}
export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PatientAdmission);
```

What is it that im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you are getting `authData` from an axios call and it won't be available till the axios request has finished

Try this

```
return(
      <div>
        <PatientCard
          dob={user.member.dateOfBirth}
        />        {this.state.authData.authorizationDocumentConfiguration && this.state.authData.authorizationDocumentConfiguration.optionFieldMap.documentTypeOption.label}                        
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: you are making an axois request in componentDidMount and since axios request take time for the data to be available and hence with `{this.state.authData.authorizationDocumentConfiguration && this.state.authData.authorizationDocumentConfiguration.optionFieldMap.documentTypeOption.label}` we are making a check for `this.state.authData.authorizationDocumentConfiguration` to be undefined. If it has value it gets passed down , otherwise a null is passed

Comment: Glad to have helped :)